# Saving A File To A Directory

Tags: java, file, directory, save

So right now, I have a server that runs on OOS/OIS and I'm trying to send a file and save it to a certain directory in my client program. I can send the file fine, but how exactly do I save the file on the client side? Thanks in advance to any responders!

Comment: Not sure I got the question right. Are you asking how to save a file on client side? If yes, what's the problem - you should simply create a file and flush all your data into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a `java.io.FileOutputStream` and write the data to the stream, and then close it. Unless its text, then create a `java.io.FileWriter` and write your text to that.

Comment: So.
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(dest);